# AngularJS - Button actives function that stops Toggle and allows to click on only one Tile

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have a Tileboard with 144 elements (divs). So far, I can apply a toggle function, to select any of these tiles to change the color. And it works fine.

main.html:

```
<div class="container" ng-controller='BoardController'>
    <div id="content">
      <div ng-style="boardStyle" class="board">
        <div ng-repeat="i in getNumber(tiles) track by $index" 
          ng-click="changeToogle($index)" ng-init="initToogle($index)" 
          ng-model="status[$index]" ng-style="status[$index]?tileStyle:lockStyle"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <nav id="sideNav">
      <h3>Controls</h3>
      <div class="btn-wrapper">
        <a ng-href="#" ng-click="startSelect()" id="start" class="button">Start</a>
        <a href="#" id="end" class="button">End</a>
        <a href="#" id="go" class="button not-active">GO!</a>
      </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

boardcontroller.js:

```
angular.module('warmup').controller('BoardController', function($scope) {

    $scope.tiles = 144;
    $scope.status = [];
    $scope.getNumber = function(num) {
        return new Array(num);   
    }

    var boardHeight = window.innerHeight/3;
    var boardWidth = boardHeight;

    var tileHeight = boardHeight/12 - .3;
    var tileWidth = tileHeight;

    $scope.boardStyle = {
        "height" : boardHeight + 'px',
        "width" : boardWidth + 'px',
        "border" : "1px solid #AAA"
    }

    var colors = [
        {name: "principal", color: "red"},
        {name: "locker", color: "blue"}, 
        {name: "path", color: "green"}
    ];

    $scope.tileStyle = {
        "height" : tileHeight + 'px',
        "width" : tileWidth + 'px',
        "border" : "1px solid #CCC",
        "background-color": colors[0].color,
        "float": "left"
    }

    $scope.lockStyle = {
        "height" : tileHeight + 'px',
        "width" : tileWidth + 'px',
        "border" : "1px solid #CCC",
        "background-color": colors[1].color,
        "float": "left"
    }
    // TOGGLE FUNCTIONS
    $scope.changeToogle = function($index) {
      $scope.status[$index] = !$scope.status[$index];
    }

    $scope.initToogle = function($index) {
      $scope.status[$index] = true;
    }

    //FUNCTION TO SET THE START POINT
    $scope.startSelect = function(){
        console.log("click");
    //HERE IS THE PROBLEM    
    }     
  });
```

In the  I have a button `id="start"`, that when it will be clicked, will call the `startSelect` function. I need this function does 2 things:

1. Stops the toggle function (the user should use the toggle before
   this step, and the clicked tiles should be keeped into the lockStyle
   style)

[image]

2. Allows the user selecting only one Tile, clicking on it. If the user
   click on one and, after that, click on another tile, just the second
   should be considered (the first would be deselected or
   disconsidered). The image below shows the selected tile in green.

[image]

Comment: But @BelgoCanadian could this "changeToggle" function start a side effect in the previous process (the toggle itself)?

Comment: forget what i said before, check out my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this (added a isStatusSelected variable and used it in your functions)
main.html:

```
<div class="container" ng-controller='BoardController'>
    <div id="content">
      <div ng-style="boardStyle" class="board">
        <div ng-repeat="i in getNumber(tiles) track by $index" 
          ng-click="changeToogle($index)" ng-init="initToogle($index)" 
          ng-model="status[$index]" ng-style="style($index)"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <nav id="sideNav">
      <h3>Controls</h3>
      <div class="btn-wrapper">
        <a ng-href="#" ng-click="startSelect()" id="start" class="button">Start</a>
        <a href="#" id="end" class="button">End</a>
        <a href="#" id="go" class="button not-active">GO!</a>
      </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

boardcontroller.js:

```
angular.module('warmup').controller('BoardController', function($scope) {

    $scope.tiles = 144;
    $scope.status = [];
    $scope.getNumber = function(num) {
        return new Array(num);
    }

    var isStatusSelected = false;

    var boardHeight = window.innerHeight/3;
    var boardWidth = boardHeight;

    var tileHeight = boardHeight/12 - .3;
    var tileWidth = tileHeight;

    $scope.boardStyle = {
        "height" : boardHeight + 'px',
        "width" : boardWidth + 'px',
        "border" : "1px solid #AAA"
    }

    var colors = [
        {name: "principal", color: "red"},
        {name: "locker", color: "blue"}, 
        {name: "path", color: "green"}
    ];

    $scope.style = function ($index) {
        if (!$scope.status[$index]) {
            $scope.status[$index] = 0;
        }       
        return {
            "height" : tileHeight + 'px',
            "width" : tileWidth + 'px',
            "border" : "1px solid #CCC",
            "background-color": colors[$scope.status[$index]].color,
            "float": "left"
        }
    }

    // TOGGLE FUNCTIONS
    $scope.changeToogle = function($index) {
        if (isStatusSelected) {
            for (var i in $scope.status) {
                if ($scope.status[i] === 2) {
                    $scope.status[i] = 0;
                }
            }
            $scope.status[$index] = 2;
        } else {
            $scope.status[$index] = ($scope.status[$index] === 0 ? 1 : 0);
        }

    }

    $scope.initToogle = function($index) {
      $scope.status[$index] = true;
    }

    //FUNCTION TO SET THE START POINT
    $scope.startSelect = function(){
        isStatusSelected = !isStatusSelected;
        console.log("click");
    //HERE IS THE PROBLEM    
    }     
  });
```

Comment: As I thought before, the "changeToggle" is not yet ok. It did not keep the Tiles selected earlier, but changed them all to the style "lockStyle" (blue color). And only the clicked Tile (which uses the "startSelect" function) is using the red color ("tileStyle"). I will edit the question by inserting an image of the board with the result prior to using the "startSelect" function. But thanks for answering.

Comment: I see, I would change your status array to an array of numbers instead of booleans then corresponding to your colors array
so if the 5th tile needs to be green: $scope.status[5] = 2 (2 being colors[2])
then your ng-style can be a function:   $scope.style = function ($index) {
        "height" : tileHeight + 'px',
        "width" : tileWidth + 'px',
        "border" : "1px solid #CCC",
        "background-color": colors[$scope.status[$index]].color,
        "float": "left"
    }

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand the logic. Who defines where the green color will appear is the user, at his click (he can only choose a Tile). Red is the default color (no action), and blue is the toggle that should be closed for choosing the starting point (green). What is the link between the $index and the position of the color in the color array?

Comment: you will store the color index in the status instead of just "true or false"

Comment: I've adjusted the answer to reflect what i was talking about!

Comment: now I got it. But it returns "TypeError: Cannot read property 'color' of undefined at b.$scope.style". And the Toggle also doesn't work anymore...

Comment: adjusted again!

Comment: Another error: "Error: [$rootScope:inprog] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.6/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24apply", showed when I click on any tile.

Comment: take out the scope apply, i thought it wasn't applying the style after it updates

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I tried this before. Nothing happens when starts (neither the toggle), and when I click on any tile: TypeError: Cannot read property 'color' of undefined at b.$scope.style

Comment: At "changeToggle" function, changing the numbers 3 for 2 (index 3 doesn't exist) and 2 for 1, the second question is solved! But the toggle function (the "else" part) are doing nothing yet (no errors, but doesn't work)...

Comment: else statement needs to be: $scope.status[$index] = ($scope.status[$index] === 0 ? 1 : 0);

Comment: That's it! It works fine now. Please update your answer so I can accept ;-) Thanks!

Comment: Adjusted to reflect what we talked about!

Comment: Feel free to send me the link to the end result, I'm curios to what you're making

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156082/discussion-between-atoyansk-and-belgocanadian).